# GET variables of parent window to iframe url

Tags: php, iframe, get

I'm trying to pass on the parent url variables to the variables of the iframe url.

For example if the parent url is: 
http://mywebsite.com/autos-zoeken?sessid=s838c7e5c3be0452fc38f4ffb6f307ed7&code=be3f&whsearch_key=6568

The iframe url needs to become: 
http://anotherwebsite.com/s838c7e5c3be0452fc38f4ffb6f307ed7/be3f/stock/6568/

The code I'm using now is:

> `<?php  $val1 = $_GET[“sessid“]; 
>            $val2 = $_GET[“code“]; 
>            $val3 = $_GET[“whsearch_key“]; 
>   echo "<iframe src='http://anotherwebsite.com/' . $val1 . '/' . $val2 . '/stock/' . $val3 . '/' id='blockrandom' width='1000' height='1200'  scrolling='auto'  frameborder='0'  class='wrapper'>  Your browser doesn't support inline frames.</iframe>"; ?>`

The result on the website is:
http://anotherwebsite.com/' .  . '/' .  . '/stock/' .  . '/' id='blockrandom1' etc

So the variables aren't being put in the right place in the iframe url

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work fine:

```
echo "<iframe src='http://anotherwebsite.com/$val1/$val2/stock/$val3/' id='blockrandom' width='1000' height='1200' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0' class='wrapper'> Your browser doesn't support inline frames.</iframe>";
```

the problem is with all your quote's inside your src, it thinks it needs to stop your src after `http://anotherwebsite.com/` and you don't need to use "." inbetween because you used doubleqouote on start, you can just use variables inside doublequotes.

Comment: Yes, it works now! I thought I had tried that already before. Anyway, good to know I was on the right track. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "<iframe src='http://anotherwebsite.com/$val1/$val2/stock/$val3/' id='blockrandom' width='1000' height='1200' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0' class='wrapper'>Your browser doesn't support inline frames.</iframe>"; ?>
```

you don't need to escape your variables

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually concatenating multiple strings, you're just building a single string.  Take a look at a simplified example:

```
"<iframe src='http://anotherwebsite.com/' . $val1"
```

That's just one string which happens to have a period between some spaces.  In order to use the `.` concatenation operator you need to terminate the string first:

```
"<iframe src='http://anotherwebsite.com/'" . $val1
```